# Neo4j in Docker - Max Heap Size Causes Hard crash 137

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, neo4j, heap-memory

I'm trying to spin up a Neo4j 3.1 instance in a Docker container (through Docker-Compose), running on OSX (El Capitan). All is well, unless I try to increase the max-heap space available to Neo above the default of 512MB.

According to [the docs](http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/docker/), this can be achieved by adding the environment variable `NEO4J_dbms_memory_heap_maxSize`, which then causes the server wrapper script to update the `neo4j.conf` file accordingly. I've checked and it is being updated as one would expect.

The problem is, when I run `docker-compose up` to spin up the container, the Neo4j instance crashes out with a **137 status code**. A little research tells me this is a [linux hard-crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31659840/my-server-exited-with-code-137), based on heap-size maximum limits.

```
$ docker-compose up
Starting elasticsearch
Recreating neo4j31
Attaching to elasticsearch, neo4j31
neo4j31          | Starting Neo4j.
neo4j31 exited with code 137
```

**My questions:**

1. Is this due to a Docker or an OSX limitation?
2. Is there a way I can modify these limits? If I drop the requested limit to 1GB, it will spin up, but still crashes once I run my heavy query (which is what caused the need for increased Heap space anyway).
3. The query that I'm running is a large-scale update across a lot of nodes (>150k) containing full-text attributes, so that they can be syncronised to ElasticSearch using the plug-in. Is there a way I can get Neo to step through doing, say, 500 nodes at a time, using only cypher (I'd rather avoid writing a script if I can, feels a little dirty for this).

My docker-compose.yml is as follows:

```
---
version: '2'
services:
 # ---<SNIP>

  neo4j:
    image: neo4j:3.1
    container_name: neo4j31
    volumes:
      - ./docker/neo4j/conf:/var/lib/neo4j/conf
      - ./docker/neo4j/mnt:/var/lib/neo4j/import
      - ./docker/neo4j/plugins:/plugins 
      - ./docker/neo4j/data:/data
      - ./docker/neo4j/logs:/var/lib/neo4j/logs
    ports:
        - "7474:7474"
        - "7687:7687"
    environment:
        - NEO4J_dbms_memory_heap_maxSize=4G

 # ---<SNIP>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Is this due to a Docker or an OSX limitation?

   **NO** Increase the amount of available RAM to Docker to resolve this issue.
2. Is there a way I can modify these limits? If I drop the requested
   limit to 1GB, it will spin up, but still crashes once I run my heavy
   query (which is what caused the need for increased Heap space
   anyway).

   [image: Docker Memory Settings]
3. The query that I'm running is a large-scale update across a lot of
   nodes (>150k) containing full-text attributes, so that they can be
   syncronised to ElasticSearch using the plug-in. Is there a way I can
   get Neo to step through doing, say, 500 nodes at a time, using only
   cypher (I'd rather avoid writing a script if I can, feels a little
   dirty for this).

   **N/A** This is a NEO4J specific question.  It might be better to seperate this from the Docker questions listed above.

Comment: Thank you, this was spot on. I was sure i was missing something crucial (I'm fairly new to Docker!). I was looking for something in the docker-compose command, but this makes much more sense!

Comment: no worries!  it's really easy to overlook the little things when you're just getting started!  sorry i couldn't answer your neo4js question.

Answer (score 2):

> 3.The query that I'm running is a large-scale update across a lot of nodes (>150k) containing full-text attributes, so that they can be syncronised to ElasticSearch using the plug-in. Is there a way I can get Neo to step through doing, say, 500 nodes at a time, using only cypher (I'd rather avoid writing a script if I can, feels a little dirty for this).

You can do this with the help of [apoc](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures) plugin for neo4j, more specifically `apoc.periodic.iterate`
or `apoc.periodic.commit`
.

If you will use `apoc.periodic.commit` your first match should be specific like in example you mark which nodes have you already synced, because it sometimes fall in the loop:

```
call apoc.periodic.commit("
match (user:User) WHERE user.synced = false
with user limit {limit}
MERGE (city:City {name:user.city})
MERGE (user)-[:LIVES_IN]->(city)
SET user.synced =true
RETURN count(*)
",{limit:10000})
```

If you use `apoc.periodic.iterate` you can run it in parallel mode:

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
"MATCH (o:Order) WHERE o.date > '2016-10-13' RETURN o",
"with {o} as o MATCH (o)-[:HAS_ITEM]->(i) WITH o, sum(i.value) as value 
CALL apoc.es.post(host-or-port,index-or-null,type-or-null,
query-or-null,payload-or-null) yield value return *", {batchSize:100, parallel:true})
```

Note that there is no need for second MATCH clause and `apoc.es.post` is a function for apoc that can send post requests to elastic search.
see [documentation](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_apoc_periodic_iterate) for more info

Comment: Thanks for this, looks to be very useful!