# Error 137 on docker build command on Win7

Tags: docker, docker-build

Executing the following command:

`docker build -m 3g --memory-swap -1 -f MyDockerfile .`

And I'm getting this:

```
Solving package specifications: .....Killed
The command '/bin/sh -c conda update -y --all &&     conda install -y -c menpo m
enpo &&     conda install -y -c menpo menpofit &&     conda install -y -c menpo
menpodetect &&     conda install -y -c menpo dlib &&     conda install -y -c men
po opencv3 &&     conda install -y joblib &&     pip install pyprind &&     pip
install colorlog' returned a non-zero code: 137
```

From googling, my understanding is that the OS is killing my running process here due to running out of memory.  I have 8gb on my host machine, and I can see that I am not going over 4gb used.  I added the memory switches above, to no discernible effect.

Since I'm running this on Win7 and the older docker toolbox, am I being limited by Oracle's VM VirtualBox?

Comment: I followed up on my own advice, and investigated Oracle's VM VirtualBox, and indeed, the default host was set to a memory of 1gb.  I increased it and looks like it's working now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42398166/2878244

You may have to increase the memory resources assigned to docker by going to the Docker Tab > Preferences > Advanced

[image: Docker advanced settings]

Comment: Is that not the same as what the `-m` switch achieves?  As I mentioned in my comment, the culprit was Oracle's VirtualBox, which was set to 1gb.

Comment: Ah, I see. It had seemed to me that the `-m` switch required one to specify a particular container, instead of Docker in general. I think that works as well @gdbj

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Docker solved it for me

[image]